# How to count the number of disjoint regions covered by a Boolean expression?

Tags: boolean-computation, logic

Consider the following Boolean expression as an example:

```
expr=(RC||NC||!(RC||NC))&&!(RC&&NC)&&(B||A)&&!(B&&A)&&((RC&&B)||(RC&&A)||(!NC&&!RC)||NC);
```

We can visualize this expression using the Venn diagram:

```
ResourceFunction["VennDiagram"][expr]
```

[image]

We can see there are 6 disjoint regions where it is `True`.

Is there a builtin function or some way to use the `guide/BooleanComputation` to create a function `TotalProduct` that can output this number:

```
TotalProduct[expr]
```

that produces

```
6
```

Comment: `SatisfiabilityCount[expr]` ?

Comment: @Syed Thank you, it seems to be working on the cases I have tested. Even higher dimensions where 2D Venn diagrams are not possible.

Comment: It is the count of  `True` outputs for a Boolean table. Try: `BooleanTable[expr]`.